# Eslinter does not work on files with .vue extension

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I recently installed eslint on my Vuejs application.

**Installed packages:**

```
eslint
eslint-plugin-vue
```

**My .eslintrc.json config**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "plugins": ["vue"],
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:vue/recommended"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
   "no-console": "off",
   "no-var": 2,  
   "indent": ["warn", 2],
   "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
   "quotes": ["error", "double"],
   "semi": ["error", "always"]
  }
}
```

When I try to define a variable with **var** in my **main.js** file, the linter works perfectly and shows up the problem at the same time.

[image]

but when I try to do the same in a **.vue** file it doesn't say anything.

[image]

Well ... at that moment I thought that Eslinter was not applying it to .vue files but here comes a little more strange ...

In that same .vue file where the var rule does not work there is another problem that eslint is pointing to ... that means that eslinter is working.

[image]

> Does anyone know why this is happening? I wanted to apply the rules for the .vue extension but I still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vscode it needs the following setting:

```
"eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    {"language": "vue", "autoFix": true}
]
```

According with this known [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/327). If its doesn't resolve, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VueCLI to create the project and it turns out to be missing configuration in `extends` of `.eslintrc` or `package.json` file. You have to add this to make it work:

```js
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/recommended"
    ]
```

As it's mentioned [here](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#installation).